# JQuery - click-Event on HTML5-Video in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a some simple HTML5-Videos on my page and I want to do stuff when a user hac clickes on one of it.

So the video is like

```
<video height="171" controls="" class="img-thumbnail" data-id="20" data-txt="" data-title="" id="img-thumbnail-20">
    <source src="./assets/files/video/end.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

and then I do:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("body").click(function(e) {            
        var classClicked = ($(e.target).attr('class')); 
        if(classClicked == "img-thumbnail") { 
        ............
```

This works on Chrome but not on FireFox. 
I also tried a `onclick="bla()"` in the video-tag, but still the same.. works in Chrome but not in Firefox

How can I catch a users click in FF ?

Comment: Perhaps using [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) will help you

Comment: `$(document).on('click', function(e) {`?

Comment: @JaromandaX.. I also tried to delegate, but still the same.

Comment: @sideroxylon.. nothing changes.. still the same.. works in Chrome but not in FF

Answer (score 0):

remove [controls=""],
to disable default controls,video default controls don't bubbling mouse left key event in firefox

code in firefox:

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) { console.log(e.target.tagName, 'mousedown') })//not bubbling from video default controls
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) { console.log(e.target.tagName, 'mouseup') })//not ...... 
window.addEventListener('click', function (e) { console.log(e.target.tagName, 'click') })//not ...... 
window.addEventListener('dblclick', function (e) { console.log(e.target.tagName, 'dblclick') })//not ...... 

window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) { console.log(e.target.tagName, 'contextmenu') })//bubbling from video default controls to html,window
window.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) { console.log(e.target.tagName, 'mouseover') })//bubbling ......
window.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) { console.log(e.target.tagName, 'mouseout') })//bubbling ......
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) { console.log(e.target.tagName, 'mousemove') })//bubbling ......
window.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) { console.log(e.target.tagName, 'wheel') })//bubbling ......
```

don't know how use firefox's default video controls,and without mouse event bubbling lost.
but chrome is no problem .